# How to remove section pagebreak in PHPWord

Tags: phpword

I am using PHPWord to create report. When I am creating a section it automatically adding a page break which I donot want.

Is there any way to remove the added page break?

or Is there any way to createSection without the page break?

Please note that I am not using any template. Just creating a doc file from database with tables and images.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having this issue too. ++ Trying to create dynamic sections but I don't want/need the page break.

Answer (score 2):

You can define how the page breaks behave with the section `breakType` style. To remove the page breaks completely from the sections just use the `continuous` value for the breakType:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('breakType' => 'continuous'));
```

or

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->getStyle()->setBreakType('continuous');
```

for more info check [phpword styles](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#section) and [phpword containers](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/docs/containers.rst)