# PHPWord: Insert page break and set margin and page orientation using Laravel 4

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHPOffice/PHPWord, and I have a MySQL Database with a table named `trials`. It contains 2 columns `id` and `name`. Both columns are `VARCHAR(255)`. There are several rows such as below:

```
id | name
---+-----------
A1 | Avatar
B1 | Browser
C1 | Calculator
A2 | Align
```

The query that I use is `SELECT * FROM trials ORDER BY id ASC`

What I'm trying to do is Make a DOC file and add a new page for each row with (1 page for 1 `id` and 1 for `name`).

How can I insert a page break between rows?

Also, how can I set the margin and page orientation?

As an example I want the content of `mytrial.doc` as below:

```
Page 01
    A1 - Avatar
Page 02
    A2 - Align
Page 03
    B1 - Browser
Page 04
    C1 - Calculator
```

I use Laravel 4 as my framework.

PS:
I already read the following:

- [how to remove section pagebreak in phpword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554893/how-to-remove-section-pagebreak-in-phpword)
- [sample paragraph pagination](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_08_ParagraphPagination.php)

Comment: The example you linked to has a "pageBreakBefore" example - does this not work for you?

Comment: But what about with the margin and page orientation ?

Comment: What about the [examples for sections](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_03_Sections.php)?

Comment: Tried, Margin seems to be cleared just the page oreintation that I did not find... Landscape or portrait

Comment: Orientation was mentioned on line 13 of the sections examples, did that not work for you?

Comment: Ah... Finnaly I found the solution. Better way for PHPWord documentation : http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html :) Thanks Phill Sparks :)

Answer (score 13):

1. You have 2 options to insert a [page break](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#page-breaks)

   - pageBreakBefore
   - addPageBreak()

     `$section->addPageBreak();`
2. Set the margin and page orientation via [Styles](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#section)

   - margin

   `$section = $phpWord->addSection(
      array('marginLeft' => 600, 'marginRight' => 600,
       'marginTop' => 600, 'marginBottom' => 600)
    );`

   - orientation

   `$section= $phpWord->addSection(array('orientation' => 'landscape'));`