# phpword how to change image position in header

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpword

I have an image that's currently located at the top of the page with the code below. I want to push down the position of the image by adding `marginTop=> 200` to the code but it doesn't work. In fact, I have tried everything that I know but all has failed. Does anyone know how to change the position of the image in the header in phpword?

```
$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->firstPage();
$header->addImage(
  '../images/logo/AVA-Full-Logo-Grey.jpg',
  array(
    'width'            => 250,
    'wrappingStyle'    => 'square',
    'marginTop'        => 200,
    'positioning'      => 'relative',
    'posHorizontal'    => PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
    'posHorizontalRel' => 'margin',
    'posVerticalRel'   => 'line',
  )
);
```

Comment: This answer may be helpful, I didn't want to mark it as a duplicate because it doesn't have an accepted answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651259/phpword-insert-page-break-and-set-margin-and-page-orientation-using-laravel-4  from their documentation it looks like your doing it the right way, http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#images, maybe something is overriding the style.

Answer (score 1):

```
$section->addHeader()->addWatermark("./image.png",
array(
    'width' => round(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToPixel(0.5842)),
    'height' => round(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToPixel(2.1336)),
    'positioning' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_ABSOLUTE,
    'posHorizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_ABSOLUTE,
    'posVertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Image::POSITION_ABSOLUTE,
    'marginLeft' => round(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToPixel(17)),
    'marginTop' => round(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToPixel(-0.5)),
    'wrappingStyle' => 'infront'
));
```

This code works for me. You need to set the positioning method to 'absolute' and then you can adjust the position by changing the 'marginLeft' and 'marginTop' parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, after a lot of examples in this way:

```
$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->addWatermark(JPATH_SITE.'/libraries/PHPWord-master/headerandfooter/image.png', array('width' => 535, 'height' => 535,'marginTop' => round(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToPixel(5.25)),'posHorizontal' => 'absolute','posVertical' => 'absolute'));
```